# Constants in limiting behavior of a function

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, asymptotics

Let say we have a function:

$$f(n) = n^2 + 2n + 5 $$

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis), limiting behavior of `f(n)` is:

$$n^2 + 2n + 5 \sim n^2 \space (as \space n \space \rightarrow \infty) $$

For example we have a function `g(n)`:

$$g(n) = 5n^3 + n$$

I'm confused what is the limiting behavior of `g(n)`:
  $$5n^3 + n \sim 5n^3 \space (as \space n \space \rightarrow \infty) $$
or just simply (without a constant 5):
  $$5n^3 + n \sim n^3 \space (as \space n \space \rightarrow \infty) $$

If latter is true, could you please explain why we drop the 5 constant?

Comment: By $a_n \sim b_n$ we usually mean $\frac {a_n} {b_n} \to 1$ as $ n \to \infty$. So it is not right to drop the constant $5$. Of course the meaning of $\sim $ in the wiki article may be different. May be they mean $\frac {a_n} {b_n} $ converges to some finite positive limit.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, according to the wiki, the following shoud be true: $${{a} \over b} \rightarrow 1$$

Comment: In that case the constant cannot be dropped.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you for clear explanation!